# Count in django using foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models, User and JobGroup, User Model has a foreign key from Job Group.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    jobgroup = models.ForeignKey(JobGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class JobGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

I want to count the number of times a job group is assigned to a user **E.G** user1 - Jobgroup A, user2 - Jobgroup B, user3-Jobgroup A, user4-Jobgroup C
The output I am looking for

- Jobgroup A-2
- Jobgroup B-1
- Jobgroup C-1
  I tried this 
  `jobcount=User.objects.all().values('jobgoup__group_name').annotate(total=Count('jobgroup__group_name'))` but it did't work.. It returns None

Comment: `JobGroup.objects.annotate(total=Count('user_set'))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
joblist = list(User.objects.all().values_list('jobgoup__group_name',flat = True).annotate(total = Count('jobgoup__group')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do *not* use `.values(..)`, it completely destroys the layer that is defined by the model. You can simply annotate your `JobGroup` objects by the number of related `User`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

JobGroup.objects.annotate(
    nuser=Count('user')
)
```

The `JobGroup` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.nuser` that contains the number of *related* `User` objects.